# i want to change user input date format to string in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am new to javascript and i have this date value (birth = 1986-12-14) and I want to change it to string, however all i get is subtraction operation.

```
var birth = 1986-12-14;
console.log(birth.toString());

output: 1960
```

I want result to be "1986-12-14"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: `var birth = 1986-12-14;` makes `birth = 1960` because `1986-12-14` isn't a date, it's a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 2):

`var birth = 1986-12-14;` makes `birth = 1960` because `1986-12-14` isn't a date, it's a mathematical expression.

If you want a date, use a **[date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)**.

> **NOTE**: Months are represented as integers that start from `0`. So, if
>   you want December, you'd use `11` for the month.

```js
var birth = new Date(1986,11,14);

// Extract the parts of the date that you want and build a string from them.
// Adjust the month for human consumption
console.log(birth.getFullYear() + "-" + (birth.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + birth.getDate());
```